# Changing default style on point GeoJSON Layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style

I need to change style on a point GeoJSON layer in a Leaflet map.

I'm using the following code:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                      if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                         layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
                      }
                     }

var myStyle = {
 "color": "#ff7800",
 "weight": 5,
 "opacity": 0.65
};

myGeoJSONLayer = L.geoJson(myGeoJSON, {
                      style: myStyle,
                      onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
             });

myGeoJSONLayer.addTo(map);
```

All is working but there is always the standard default blue marker on my map.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To change point markers, you should use the `pointToLayer` function. See the [example page](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html).

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJson(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```